# Spinner Array List

Tags: android, json

The spinner items come from JSON object. I already get the JSON object and put in the spinner. But I have this kind of issue at spinner in android that if I choose a cat from spinner choices and after I clicked, it will not show on the spinner item selected. See the picture for the sample. Is there anything wrong or I forgot to add some lines of code.

[image]

UPDATED: image and XML
[image]

XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerdropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bckg_spinner"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA

```
public class ProfileDept extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> ArrayListSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiledept);
    process.execute();

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerdropdown);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ArrayListSpinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
    class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://Account/api/Profile?TestAccount");
                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");   //POST or GET
                httpsURLConnection.connect();

                int statusCode = httpsURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                statusMsg = httpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage();

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    InputStream it = new BufferedInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(it);
                    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
                    StringBuilder dta = new StringBuilder();
                    String chunks;

                    while ((chunks = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                        dta.append(chunks);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(dta.toString());

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonpass = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            ArrayListSpinner.add(jsonpass.getString("Username"));
                        }

                    }
                    return dta.toString();

                } else {

                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: remove this line  ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: Th image is just a sample. nothing to do with color. Sorry for mistake, i already update the image that are exactly like in my android layout

Comment: Add your XML too

Comment: xml has been added in post

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your text color to white when item is selected. so Item is displayed but due to your background and font color is white, it is not displayed. Change It to any other color and check.

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);   // set to green 
        }
```

Comment: Th image is just a sample. nothing to do with color. Sorry for mistake, i already update the image that are exactly like in my android layout.

Comment: can you debug your code what happens when onitemclicklistener called.

Comment: D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xcc552200 (DropDownListView) with handle 0xc6025280
 
from LOGCAT

Comment: can you remove or comment code for onitemselected and try once.

Comment: same output problem.  nothing change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181653/discussion-between-karan-mer-and-no-name).

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
int index = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
((TextView) spinner.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue)); //<----}
```